# Using custom php file for ajax url inside plugin

Tags: plugins, ajax

Inside a subdirectory of my plugin I have a file called insertproducts.php and I need to call that through an Ajax request. I have something like this:

```
        $.ajax({ 
            url:  "insertproducts.php",
        }).done(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
```

But the script cannot find the file and tries to look for:

```
http://example.com/wp-admin/insertproducts.php
```

Looking around to find out the problem and I read that WP points all the ajax requests to admin-ajax.php.

How do I run my custom url now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read more about [AJAX in Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).

How to use Ajax in WP:
1. Register file contain functions, event of javascript or jquery. All data will be submit by events js

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ajax_scripts' );
function ajax_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'main-ajax', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/main-ajax.js', array(), '', true );
    $arr = array(
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
    );
    wp_localize_script('main-ajax','obj',$arr );
    wp_enqueue_script('main-ajax');
}
```

inside main-ajax.js (data will be process through by admin-ajax.php) :

```
$.ajax({ 
    url:  obj.ajaxurl,
}).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

2. File PHP to process functions (insertproducts.php) after submit data by ajax. Use below action for your function.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action');
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. Optical. About the last part, Do you mean that I move all the scripts from my insertproducts.php into my_action function? Also why my_action call back has been called twice? Once for wp_ajax_my_action and once for wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action hooks? Wouldn't that cause problem?

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem. The script still looks for admin-ajax.php inside wp-admin. Event if I change  'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php') to 'ajaxurl'=>'insertproducts.php' it still looks for /wp-admin/insertproducts.php, strange!

Comment: OK, thanks Mr. Optical. I change  the line to 'ajaxurl' => plugin_dir_url( __DIR__ ) .'insertproducts.php'

Comment: "The script still looks for admin-ajax.php inside wp-admin" That is because admin-ajax.php *is* in /wp-admin.